# When i plug in usb camera i get 2 devices

Tags: linux, usb, devices, v4l

When I plug in the camera to Linux then I get 2 devices `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`
Why is that happens and is that normal?
Odd numbered devices do not work.
/dev/v4l/by-path looks like that:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 dets  15 01:29 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:14:1.0-video-index0 -> ../../video0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 dets  15 01:29 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:14:1.0-video-index1 -> ../../video1
```

/dev/v4l/by-id looks like that:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 dets  15 01:29 usb-_Webcam_C170-video-index0 -> ../../video0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 dets  15 01:29 usb-_Webcam_C170-video-index1 -> ../../video1
```

I tested it with 2 computers(Kubuntu 18.10) and with 4 different cameras. it makes always 2 devices.

Edit added dmesg output:

```
[118541.028706] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[118541.254215] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=082b, bcdDevice=28.25
[118541.254221] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[118541.254225] usb 1-14: Product: Webcam C170
[118541.254229] usb 1-14: Manufacturer:  
[118541.310835] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[118541.323429] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[118541.332766] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[118541.334867] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Webcam C170 (046d:082b)
[118541.354970] uvcvideo 1-14:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[118541.354971] uvcvideo 1-14:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[118541.354972] uvcvideo 1-14:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[118541.355016] input: Webcam C170: Webcam C170 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/input/input51
[118541.355077] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[118541.355078] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Comment: It depends on the camera model. What does `ls -l /dev/v4l/by-id` look like? If a camera has an error in its USB device/endpoint descriptors (= within the camera firmware), it might well produce strange results like this.

Comment: I added details

Comment: What does dmesg say (relevant lines at the time shortly after plugging the camera)?

Comment: What about `lsusb`? And `lspci` if it has any pertinent information.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem starting from 4.18 kernel. In 4.15 it was working fine. Pretty annoying, because I'm writing a computer vision application and opening all of the devices. Now I have to filter them to the working ones.

Comment: Same issue. I connect two cameras. ls -l /dev/v4l/by-id/ shows two cameras bus lsusb sees four cameras and four mics. EDIT: Now I see four cameras on /dev/v4l/by-id/ too!

Comment: This was added in kernel 4.16 - the second device provides metadata. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539573/13613 for more details.

Comment: @JohnTESlade It should be written as answer and then we could close this question.