# Multiple /dev/video for one physical device

Tags: devices, video, camera

First some specs: my computer is an HP EliteBook 8460p. It comes with an integrated Chicony HP HD webcam.

My issue is that a lot of applications (well, at least Skype and guvcview) are displaying multiple lines for the same webcam; indeed, if I do `ls -l /dev | grep video`, I get the following:

```
crw-rw----  1 root video      29,   0 Apr 16 08:13 fb0
crw-rw----  1 root video     243,   0 Apr 16 08:13 media0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   0 Apr 16 08:13 video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   1 Apr 16 08:13 video1
```

I have 2 `/dev/video[n]` with only one (integrated) webcam; Skype will work properly with `/dev/video0`, but not with `/dev/video1`. Same for guvcview.

If I plug another USB webcam, for example a logitech one, I get the following with `dmesg`:

```
[21222.638802] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[21222.970684] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08c2, bcdDevice= 0.05
[21222.970755] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[21222.972518] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:08c2)
[21226.044535] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[21226.044538] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 8 was not initialized!
[21226.044540] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 10 was not initialized!
[21226.044541] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 9 was not initialized!
[21226.044543] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[21226.044545] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[21226.044547] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[21226.044746] input: UVC Camera (046d:08c2) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:25:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input35
[21226.137559] usb 2-2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=3072), cval->res is probably wrong.
[21226.137569] usb 2-2: [5] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = 4608/7680/1
```

And the following with `ls -l /dev/ | grep video`:

```
crw-rw----  1 root video      29,   0 Apr 16 08:13 fb0
crw-rw----  1 root video     243,   0 Apr 16 08:13 media0
crw-rw----  1 root video     243,   1 Apr 16 14:06 media1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   0 Apr 16 08:13 video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   1 Apr 16 08:13 video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   2 Apr 16 14:06 video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   3 Apr 16 14:06 video3
```

3 new entries: `/dev/media1`, `/dev/video2` and `/dev/video3`.

I even found a Sony webcam (CEVCECM) that adds up to 4 new devices. The `dmesg` logs:

```
[21927.665747] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[21927.817330] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice= 9.01
[21927.817339] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[21927.817343] usb 2-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[21927.824119] hub 2-2:1.0: USB hub found
[21927.824814] hub 2-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[21928.113733] usb 2-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[21928.223184] usb 2-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=097b, bcdDevice=21.12
[21928.223192] usb 2-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[21928.223197] usb 2-2.4: Product: CEVCECM
[21928.223201] usb 2-2.4: Manufacturer: Sony
[21928.223206] usb 2-2.4: SerialNumber: DHZD10412EUHK1
[21928.227506] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device CEVCECM (054c:097b)
[21928.242592] uvcvideo: Unable to create debugfs 2-24 directory.
[21928.242780] uvcvideo 2-2.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[21928.242783] uvcvideo 2-2.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[21928.242785] uvcvideo 2-2.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[21928.242787] uvcvideo 2-2.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[21928.242877] input: CEVCECM: CEVCECM as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:25:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.4/2-2.4:1.0/input/input38
```

And the resulting device files with `ls -l /dev | grep video`:

```
crw-rw----  1 root video      29,   0 Apr 16 08:13 fb0
crw-rw----  1 root video     243,   0 Apr 16 08:13 media0
crw-rw----  1 root video     243,   1 Apr 16 14:18 media1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   0 Apr 16 08:13 video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   1 Apr 16 08:13 video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   2 Apr 16 14:18 video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   3 Apr 16 14:18 video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   4 Apr 16 14:18 video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   5 Apr 16 14:18 video5
```

5 new entries: `/dev/media1` and `/dev/video2` to `/dev/video5`.

I feel like the correct files to use are the `/dev/media[n]` ones, but Skype and guvcview somehow fail to do so and fallback to the `/dev/video[n]`.

I don't have this issue with Webcamoid for example.

If anyone has an idea, I take it. In the meantime I will continue the investigation...

**--- Edited the 2019-05-14 ---**

Got some interesting information using `v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video* --all`. For the Chicony HP HD webcam, its 2 device files have different device capabilities:

```
# Devices capabilities for /dev/video0
Video Capture
Streaming
Extended Pix Format

# Devices capabilities for /dev/video1
Metadata Capture
Streaming
Extended Pix Format
```

I get similar results for the USB webcams. So after all, maybe what Skype and guvcview fail to do is to only list video devices that support the `Video Capture` device capability.

Comment: Might be worth to use `lsusb` with enough `-v` to see the various interfaces and their properties in the USB descriptor, and compare to what you get in terms of `media*` and `video*` interfaces.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The second device provides metadata about the video data from the first device.  The new devices were introduced by this patch:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=088ead25524583e2200aa99111bea2f66a86545a

More information on the V4L metadata interface can be found here:

https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/userspace-api/v4l/dev-meta.html

For run of the mill USB Video Class devices, this mostly just provides [more accurate timestamp information](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt-meta-uvc.html).  For cameras like Intel's RealSense line, [provide a wider range of data about how the image was captured](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt-meta-d4xx.html).

Presumably this data was split out into a separate device node because it couldn't easily be delivered on the primary device node in a compatible way.  It's a bit of a pain though, since (a) applications that don't care about this metadata now need to filter out the extra devices, and (b) applications that do care about the metadata need a way to tie the two devices together.

Comment: Thank you for the links, and the answer. I guess sending a feedback to both the Skype and guvcview teams is my best bet then. :^)

Comment: For the record, this commit was first included in linux v4.16-rc1 https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/088ead25524583e2200aa99111bea2f66a86545a

Answer (score 9):

Really annoying, but just found a solution: let udev assign symlinks for device nodes just for the "real" cams, not the metadata. They are identical (?) to udev, i.e.

`udevadm info -n /dev/video0` is the "same" as 
`udevadm info -n /dev/video1`, but they get a different ATTR{index}.  So for my 2 cams I ended up with the following `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-cam.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{idVendor}=="eb1a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="299f", ATTR{index}=="0", MODE="0664", GROUP="video", SYMLINK+="cams/cam1"

SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1908", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2311", ATTR{index}=="0", MODE="0664", GROUP="video", SYMLINK+="cams/cam2"
```

After that just use `/dev/cams/camX` in your application instead of the `/dev/videoY`

Comment: This great solution made my day!

Comment: From looking ad udevadm output, initially I also landed at this solution. However, the index doesn't seem to be stable, sometimes the two devices switch after a reboot.