# What is the "Integrated I" camera on Lenovo Thinkpad laptop?

Tags: thinkpad, camera

My laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T490s, Ubuntu 20.04) shows 2 different cameras for the integrated cameras:

```
[   12.274248] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated Camera (13d3:56ba)
[   12.285342] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input20
[   12.286838] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated Camera (13d3:56ba)
[   12.288919] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated I as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/input/input21
```

The cameras can be seen on the laptop as two separate physical cameras. The *Integrated C* is clearly the normal webcam. The *Integrated I* camera on the other hand appears to give a low resolution, dark black&white image.

**What is this *Integrated I* camera, and is it possible to do something useful with it on Linux?**

Comment: I think [this may answer your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512759/multiple-dev-video-for-one-physical-device).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `I` camera is the Infrared Sensor (some [explanations](https://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2017/10/22/thinkpad-infrared-camera/)), mainly used for facial recognition (like Windows Hello).
The `C` device is the real sensor in this case