# How many webcam devices in my os?

Tags: camera

I have only one usb-camera device connected to my pc.

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2bdf:0284 SN0002 HIK 1080P CAMERA
```

It shows that it is `SN0002 HIK 1080P CAMERA`.
Why the ls command displaying two devices?

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jan 27 08:30 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jan 27 08:30 /dev/video0
```

Comment: You actually have one camera. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539573/414186) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123601/four-dev-video-entries-but-just-one-camera)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple /dev/video for one physical device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512759/multiple-dev-video-for-one-physical-device)